# Cleaner way to get the contents of a file as string in Rust?

Tags: file-io, rust

As my first dive into Rust in a while, I started writing code to dump the contents of a file to a string, for later processing (right now I'm just printing it out though)

Is there a cleaner way to do this than I currently am? It seems like I'm having to be way too verbose about it, but I'm not seeing any good way to clean it up

```
use std::io;
use std::io::File;
use std::os;
use std::str;

fn main() {
    println!("meh");
    let filename = &os::args()[1];
    let contents = match File::open(&Path::new(filename)).read_to_end() {
        Ok(s) => str::from_utf8(s.as_slice()).expect("this shouldn't happen").to_string(),
        Err(e) => "".to_string(),
    };
    println!("ugh {}", contents.to_string());
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Editor's note: review [the linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31192956/whats-the-de-facto-way-of-reading-and-writing-files-in-rust-1-x) for a maintained answer with shorter / cleaner answers.

[`Read::read_to_string`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_to_string) is the shortest I know of:

```
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;

fn main() {
    let mut file = File::open("/etc/hosts").expect("Unable to open the file");
    let mut contents = String::new();
    file.read_to_string(&mut contents).expect("Unable to read the file");
    println!("{}", contents);
}
```

Having to think about failure cases is something that Rust likes to place front and center.

Comment: You should not use `unwrap` in production code. Either `match`, `map` or `and_then`.

Comment: @hauleth That's a very strict pronouncement. Are you making the same claim for `panic`, `unreachable`, or `assert`? All of these generate a thread panic. There's plenty of reasons to `panic` in production code. Specifically, I'd state that coding **logic errors** *should* cause a panic when they are encountered. Of course, this example isn't production code, and handling error cases is up to the user of the example and the context of that application.

Comment: IMHO yes. You should avoid all of them if you can. Personally I use them only if I'm certain that this won't panic (i. e. `FromPrimitive` on constants). If I need to panic then it should happen in `main`. In libraries you should return `Result` or `Option`, or use `log` crate if it isn't fatal.

Comment: @Hauleth If the error isn't recoverable, it's oftentimes more useful to abort right when you receive it and get a stack trace rather than pass the error all the way up to `main` and thereby lose all context about the error. `panic` and `expect` have their uses.

Comment: I do wish there was a `fn read_as_string() -> Result<String>` for when we don't already have a buffer. Would be more ergonomic in many places.

Comment: @Ponkadoodle read the linked duplicate. There is such a function in the next version of Rust.

Comment: Exactly the code snippet I needed!  +1